# How to set parameters for scipy.stats distribution with a list

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am using the package `fitter` to fit continuous distributions to numpy arrays of data in Python. `fitter.fitted_param` returns a dictionary of tupples of varying length with the best-fit parameters for each distribution. These are the same parameters used to set these distributions in `scipy.stats`. I would like to use these tuples to set the parameters directly with `scipy.stats`, but I do not know how to do so. Any ideas?

Example:

```
>from fitter import Fitter
>import numpy as np
>data = np.random.random((1000,1))
>f = Fitter(data,distributions = ['norm','gamma'])
>f.fit()
>param = f.fitted_param['gamma']
>param
out:(20759.430545279687, -41.012521759919224, 0.0019996776498165851)
```

If I now want to create a new gamma distribution to generate gamma-distributed random values with the same `a`,`loc` and `scale` specified in `param` above, I need to write:

```
>from scipy import stats
>rv = stats.gamma(a=param[0],loc=param[1],scale=param[2])
>rv.rvs(100)
```

How can I set `a`,`loc`,and`scale` directly without typing them out explicitly? I want to be able to quickly fit any distribution with an arbitrary number of parameters and generate random values that follow that distribution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `<distribution>(*param)`, provided that the list of parameters `param` is in the right order.

If it is not, you have to have your params in a dictionary and call it as keyword arguments with `<distribution>(**param)`, for instance:

```
param = {"a": 20759, "scale": 0.001, "loc": -41}
stats.gamma(**param)
```

Edit: more information here: [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Thanks - that was incredibly easy. I appreciate the link as well!